# TornadoFX - remove item with ContextMenu right click option

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

So I have a table view that displays an `observedArrayList` of Accounts`Account(name, login, pass)`, those are data classes. When I right click a cell there pops an option of delete. What I want to do is delete that `Account` from the `observedArrayList`

Only I can not find any way to do this. I am not experienced with JavaFX or TornadoFX and I also can't find the answer with google or in the TornadoFX guides and docs.

This is my code:

```
class ToolView : View() {
    override val root = VBox()


    companion object handler {

        //val account1 = Account("Google", "martvdham@gmail.com", "kkk")
        //val account2 = Account("Google", "martvdham@gmail.com", "Password")
        var accounts = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Account>(

        )
        var gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
        val ggson = Gson()

        fun writeData(){
            FileWriter("accounts.json").use {
                ggson.toJson(accounts, it)
            }
        }

        fun readData(){
            accounts.clear()
            FileReader("accounts.json").use{
                var account = gson.fromJson(it, Array<Account>::class.java)
                if(account == null){return}
                for(i in account){
                    accounts.add(i)
                }
            }

        }
    }


    init {
        readData()
        borderpane {
            center {
                tableview<Account>{
                    items = accounts

                    column("Name", Account::name)
                    column("Login", Account::login)
                    column("Password", Account::password)

                    contextMenu = ContextMenu().apply{
                        menuitem("Delete"){
                            selectedItem?.apply{// HERE IS WHERE THE ITEM DELETE CODE SHOULD BE}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            bottom{
                button("Add account").setOnAction{
                    replaceWith(AddView::class, ViewTransition.SlideIn)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: A quick note on syntax :) TornadoFX has a builder for ContextMenu so Instead of `contextMenu = ContextMenu().apply{` simply write `contextmenu {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify @Martacus's answer, in your case you only need to replace `// HERE IS WHERE THE ITEM DELETE CODE SHOULD BE` with `accounts.remove(this)` and you're in business.

You could also replace the line

```
selectedItem?.apply{ accounts.remove(this) }
```

with

```
selectedItem?.let{ accounts.remove(it) }
```

From my experience, `let` is more common than `apply` when you are just using a value instead of setting up a receiver.

---

Note that the process will be different if the `accounts` list is constructed asynchronously and copied in, which is the default behavior of `asyncItems { accounts }`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1):

`selectedItem` is the item you have selected/rightclicked. 
Then you can use `arraylist.remove(selectedItem)`